# Ошибка при получении данных из item?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Добрый день, есть таблица в tabeWidget из её строки пытаюсь получить копию во вторую tabeWidget_2 данной конструкцией

```
ui->tableWidget_2->setItem(1,1, item);
```

но в консоль выскакивает ошибка

> QTableWidget: cannot insert an item that is already owned by another QTableWidget

Comment: Вы хотите, что бы эта строка "переместилась" в другую таблицу или там появилась копия?

Comment: @KoVadim появилась копия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка абсолютно ожидаемая - item не может быть "слугой двух господ" - у него должен быть один родитель. А Вы пытаетесь его добавить сразу в два. а item - это же просто указатель. Вам нужно сделать копию автоматически (а в этом поможет функция clone) или ручками (создавая новый QTableWidgetItem и заполняя его данными).

Поэтому, скорее всего должно работать такое

```
ui->tableWidget_2->setItem(1,1, item->clone());
```